# Is there a way to use My BAT coins which I moved to Coinomi Ethereum wallet By mistake?

Tags: ether, etherscan, altcoin

I didn't understand that Coinomi Ethereum wallet doesn't support BAT coins and I transfered my coin into that account.

Is There a way to use my coins? or they are lost for good?

Comment: If it's an exchange you have to contact their support. If it's a wallet (if you have the private key) then you can move them onwards.

Comment: yes coinomi is a multi coin wallet and one of them is ethereum wallet, can you tell me how can I move them using private key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coinomi does support BAT natively, you can add it from the "Add tokens - Ethereum" list. Use the search button to find it, it's listed just as "BAT", not as "Basic Attention Token".

Remember that like every token transfer, you must have some ETH in your Ethereum wallet to cover the miner fees. 0.002 ETH is usually more than enough.

Coinomi also supports every Ethereum token, you can follow the [instructions linked on George's answer](https://coinomi.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/29000009779-how-to-manually-add-an-erc20-token-) or contact Coinomi support directly.

Answer (score 0):

This should help: https://coinomi.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/29000009779-how-to-manually-add-an-erc20-token-

You can always open a ticket with Coinomi's 24/7/365 Support at: https://support.coinomi.com/

Answer (score 0):

Both previous answers are great for your specific question. I'd just like to add that no matter which wallet you use, it is very unlikely tokens would be stuck. All you need is a way to export your private key, so you can import it to a different wallet, e.g., for Coinomi like this: https://coinomi.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/29000009717-what-is-the-recovery-tool-and-how-do-i-export-my-private-keys-.